# PHP / AJAX - Access javascript file array with $_FILES in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this as HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="foo" multiple/>
```

This javascript:

```
$("#foo").change(function(){
   var files = $(this)[0].files; 
   $.ajax({
      // ???
   });
});
```

This PHP (*upload.php*):

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    // Upload code
```

Currently the files are being read correctly from the input box.
I want to use these files inside the upload.php. I have a different dropzone on my page which uses this upload.php. I don't want to write unneccesary double code so I would like to use this file again. However, I cannot send an ajax request with `$_FILES`.

**TL;DR:** How can I send an array with files with ajax to a PHP Url and use it there with $_FILES ?

Notes:
+ My input is not in a < form > 
+ It is possible to select multiple files, so I need to pass multiple files to the php file

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
var file = files[i];
   formData.append('files[]', file, file.name);
}
$.post( 'somewhere', formData, callback);
```

Not the exact code, but it should get you started.